# Autonomously map entire indoor

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to use for instance navigation stack to automatically map a building?
Meaning i dont have to send any goals to it and it will automatically discover the building till it is fully done.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246836/autonomously-map-entire-indoor/) by [gijsje170](https://answers.ros.org/users/25135/gijsje170/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2016-10-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gijsje170](https://answers.ros.org/users/25135/gijsje170/) on 2016-10-31**:
Yea sorry i mean just a single floor :P
Also i triend frontier exploration a bit but it is way to rescource heavy for my raspberry Pi are there any other known alternatives?

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2016-10-31**:
You sure its the exploration node that eats the cpu? Its probably the costmap that needs some tuning (less px/m)

**Comment by [gijsje170](https://answers.ros.org/users/25135/gijsje170/) on 2016-11-01**:
Sure i will give it a try and see via top what exactly takes most of my cpu. It could also be due to the simulation running on the pi. It is probably due to the simulation running on the pi. Although the package needs some tuning it is very good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you really want to map a building? Or just a single floor? A single floor could be done with [frontier exploration](http://wiki.ros.org/frontier_exploration). But the whole navigation stack is only 2d.

---

Originally posted by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) with karma: 1504 on 2016-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0